# Discord bot animated emoji unable to fetch and use as reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to fetch an **animated emoji** from server that my bot is not in, however I able to send that emoji to my server through it's link and via await.. But when I try to fetch it using "get_emoji()" method, and use it as a reaction, It shows an error : **Unknown Emoji**.

Following is the code:

```
 if message.channel.id == 852947148310839303: 
      emoji=bot.get_emoji("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/819465471786221570.gif?v=1") 
      await message.add_reaction(f"{emoji}")
      return
```

I have also tried by pasting emoji's ID by **<a:emoji_name:emoji_id>**, but in both cases url and emoji code, the error I am getting is same : *Unknown Emoji*.

What am I doing wrong? and is there any other way of fetching animated emojis and use it as reactions?

Comment: This is because when you use `send ()`, you aren't sending emoji, you send a gif file. I don't think it is possible to use emojis from servers that the bot isn't in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use emojis from servers that the bot is not in.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for the `get_emoji` method is supposed to be the emoji ID you're trying to get, not what it's supposed to look like/its emoji link.

So instead of

```py
bot.get_emoji("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/819465471786221570.gif?v=1")
```

it's

```py
bot.get_emoji(819465471786221570)
```

Have a great day!